# Determining trend statistic for two time series

Tags: regression, goodness-of-fit, curve-fitting, hypothesis-testing

I have two time series: one with reported scatter plot points, and a solid line that represents a fit to the data based on other variables. Here:
https://docs.google.com/document/d/1gizOAV8ZjaATLm-Ihw4tc-PqZhDwTGyXibJUG20dvqk/edit?usp=sharing

While the fit does not cover the magnitude exactly, I am more interested in the seasonal trend of peaks and falls, and how the fit line follows these. Is there some sort of statistical test that can represent this? R^2 does not do so, correct?

Comment: Could you describe in further detail what information or values would your ideal statistic return?

Comment: Some statistic that represents similar oscillations, in terms of period and matched peaks. But the amplitudes do not have to match. Is there some sort of statistic?

Comment: I am afraid you are not giving enough detail to understand your request. I assume you want the fitted values to properly capture the oscillations in your data. If you could expand your question with the context and goal of your problem it would be easier. Perhaps a non-parametric method would work for your goal. Otherwise, if it is a matter of capturing different seasonality patterns in your fit you could compare different SARIMA models, for example.